# Default role in ASP.Net built in authentication

Tags: asp.net

I am using the built in authentication in ASP.Net.
I want to make it so that when users register they are automatically added in a role that I created. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you use the default Asp .Net membership and role providers. If you use `CreateUserWizard`, in `OnCreatedUser` handler you can simply execute something like this:

```
string userName = Membership.GetUser().UserName;
Roles.AddUserToRole(userName, "<role>");
```

Comment: I know this is old, but can we all agree to show the imported namespaces? using System.Web.Security.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
string user ="";
user = RegisterUser.UserName.ToString();
Roles.AddUserToRole(user, "Employee");
```

example:

```
 protected void RegisterUser_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(RegisterUser.UserName, createPersistentCookie: false);



        string continueUrl = RegisterUser.ContinueDestinationPageUrl;
        if (!OpenAuth.IsLocalUrl(continueUrl))
        {
            continueUrl = "~/";
        }
        string user ="";
        user = RegisterUser.UserName.ToString();
        Roles.AddUserToRole(user, "Employee");
        Response.Redirect(continueUrl);
    }
```

Comment: It might be useful if you also explain how it works and why you do it in this way.

Comment: it just works very good .... i have not invented Asp.net, so just following the rules of use the inventors of asp.net and visual studio wants us developers to follow, thats why

Comment: We would learn more from you if you commented on which rules you followed :-)